# The title of contest is "Relations" but as a first timer I don't know what they expect

Tags: digital

It is the first time in my life I am participating in any photography contest . The topic they gave is **Relations** . But I am unable to figure out which types of photos go under this description.  Relation of what? human relations? Or what exactly ?

And guidance or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the fun of a contest is to see what people come up with given the title. Relations can be people holding hands, oil floating on water, a dog and a cat, the moon and the sun. It could be something nobody thought of beforehand but is suddenly clear given your picture. Alternatively it could be something everybody thought of but is portrayed in an unexpected way or extremely beautiful way.

In short: be creative!